# How to trick programs into thinking they're running under 32-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, api, hook, bypass

Basically I have 3 executables in my Windows 7 64-bit, those are:

**Loader.exe** -> This is a 32-bit exe

**x86.exe** -> This is a 32-bit exe

**x64.exe** -> This is a 64-bit exe

When **Loader.exe** starts it determines if the system is 32-bit or 64-bit and loads the appropriate file (either **x86.exe** or **x64.exe**), since I'm running a 64-bit operating system the **x64.exe** will start.

I'd like to know how **Loader.exe** determines if my system 32 or 64? Which is most likely through the API call **Kernel32.IsWow64Process()**

Now I have to make that function always return FALSE, on a global scale and not just for **Loader.exe**,
So I was hoping something along the lines of a "global api hook" which makes the function always return FALSE.

But I do not know how to do this, the last time I ever hooked something was in Windows 98 and things have changed since then.

So do you happen to know how to Hook **IsWow64Process()** and thereby making the process believe it is running in a 32bit environment?

Comment: This varies depending on the OS. Most programs just distribute a separate binary for 32/64 bit systems, with the distribution method deciding which to use (which, again, varies by OS)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it is Windows 7.
And there is a "loader" executable which decides which version to run

Comment: I think for answers to make sense you need to explain why you would want to "trick programs into thinking ... 32bit"

Comment: can you please edit your question & move the answer to the answers section?

Comment: *> I'd like to know how [to make] Kernel32.IsWow64Process()… always return FALSE, on a global scale.*     That is impossible; the system would crash horribly (if it can even boot up) and may possibly even explode or infect you with Ebola.

Comment: @ÆlessNorm if you ever happen to return, leave a comment here and we can re-attribute the answer to your user account.

Answer (score 8):

After hours of wrapping my head around the Windows API (and undocumented API), as well as pointers and what not, I finally found out how to do it.
It was kinda tricky, because **IsWow64Process()** is called by Windows on every executable even before the program reaches it's EntryPoint, if you just reflect FALSE it is going to crash.

But I noticed that the Window's calls are coming from loaded modules, and in this way I can restrict my hook to only reflect FALSE if the caller is an executable.

Here is a small guide on how it was done:

1. Get the return address of my hook, and find out which module called
   my hooked function:

   ```
   wchar_t RetAdr[256];
   wsprintf(RetAdr, L"%p", _ReturnAddress());

   HMODULE hModule;
   GetModuleHandleEx( GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, RetAdr , &hModule);
   ```
2. Take the ModuleFileName, check if it contains ".exe" and put
   "Wow64Process" variable to FALSE if it is an executable:

   ```
   wchar_t mName[MAX_PATH];
   GetModuleFileName(hModule, mName, sizeof(mName));

   const wchar_t *shortName = L".exe";
   BOOL res = TRUE;

   if(wcsstr(mName,shortName) == NULL)
        res = Orig_IsWow64Process(hProcess, Wow64Process);
   else
       *Wow64Process = FALSE;


   return res;
   ```

But here is another problem, **IsWow64Process()** does only exist on Windows 64-bit operating systems, so most programs that actually check if the operating system is 64-bit do not run that function, instead they ask if the function is available and thereby determine if the system is 32-bit or 64-bit.

The way they do this is by calling **GetProcAddress()**.

Unfortunately, **GetProcAddress()** is used in my source code to find function addresses, and hooking the function will of course result in undesired behaviour, so we delve a little deeper into the undocumented API and we find out that **Kernel32.GetProcAddress()** calls **ntdll.LdrGetProcedureAddress()**.

After reading abit on the net, I am now sure that it is safe to hook **LdrGetProcedureAddress()**.

In our hooked **LdrGetProcedureAddress()** function we check if the caller is asking for **IsWow64Process** and tell the caller that the function does **NOT** exist!

Now, we need to inject our hook into every (new) process, I decided to use the **AppInit_DLLs** method because I am already familiar with it and it does the job very well.

Theres alot of information about **AppInit_DLLs** on the web, but all of them refer to 32bit and their solution does not really work on my Windows 7 64-bit OS. 
To make it easier for you, here are the correct registry paths for 32-bit and 64-bit AppInit_DLLs:

**32-bit**:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows

**64-bit**:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ **Wow6432Node** \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows

We set **LoadAppInit_DLLs** to 0x1 and **AppInit_DLLs** to our DLL path.

Here is the final source code, it uses [mhook library](http://codefromthe70s.org/mhook22.aspx) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mhook/mhook-lib/mhook.h"

#include <intrin.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void * _ReturnAddress(void);

#pragma intrinsic(_ReturnAddress)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Defines and typedefs
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI* _ldrGPA)(IN HMODULE ModuleHandle, IN PANSI_STRING FunctionName                 
OPTIONAL, IN WORD Oridinal OPTIONAL, OUT PVOID *FunctionAddress ); 

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *_IsWow64Process)(
  __in   HANDLE hProcess,
  __out  PBOOL Wow64Process
);


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Original function

PVOID HookWow, OrigWow; 

_IsWow64Process Orig_IsWow64Process = (_IsWow64Process)
GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"Kernel32"), "IsWow64Process");

_ldrGPA Orig_ldrGPA = (_ldrGPA)
GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "LdrGetProcedureAddress");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Hooked function
NTSTATUS NTAPI Hooked_ldrGPA(IN HMODULE ModuleHandle, IN PANSI_STRING FunctionName 
OPTIONAL, IN WORD Oridinal OPTIONAL, OUT PVOID *FunctionAddress)
{
//16:00 check if FunctionName equals IsWow64Process then return NULL

return Orig_ldrGPA(ModuleHandle,OPTIONAL FunctionName, OPTIONAL Oridinal,      
                        FunctionAddress); 
}



BOOL WINAPI HookIsWow64Process(
  __in   HANDLE hProcess,
  __out  PBOOL Wow64Process
)
{
HMODULE hModule;

wchar_t RetAdr[256];
wsprintf(RetAdr, L"%p", _ReturnAddress());

GetModuleHandleEx( GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, RetAdr , &hModule);

wchar_t mName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(hModule, mName, sizeof(mName));

const wchar_t *shortName = L".exe";
BOOL res = TRUE;

if(wcsstr(mName,shortName) == NULL)
     res = Orig_IsWow64Process(hProcess, Wow64Process);
else
    *Wow64Process = FALSE;


return res;
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Entry point

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
__in HINSTANCE  hInstance,
__in DWORD      Reason,
__in LPVOID     Reserved
)
{        
switch (Reason)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    OrigWow = Orig_IsWow64Process;
    HookWow = HookIsWow64Process;
    Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&Orig_IsWow64Process, HookIsWow64Process);
    Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&Orig_ldrGPA, Hooked_ldrGPA);
    break;

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    Mhook_Unhook((PVOID*)&Orig_IsWow64Process);
    Mhook_Unhook((PVOID*)&Orig_ldrGPA);
    break;
}

return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never force 64 bit program to run as 32 bit. Because 64 bit programs are assembled as 64 bit instructions at a time.But when you run 32 bit program on 64 bit processor the os convert 32 bit system calls to 64 bit format. The same question has been answered here check this out. 
[Force application to run in 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows](https://superuser.com/q/383200/143512)

Comment: Exactly, unless emulated but that would make it extremely slow...

Comment: Please flag duplicate questions as such rather than answering them. Thank you.

Comment: Understand me correctly, I'm not forcing a 64-bit compiled program to run under a 32-bit environment. I am forcing a loader.exe to believe the system is 32-bit and therefore load the 32-bit version of the program instead of the 64-bit.

Comment: @ÆlessNorm I thought you explained yourself rather well.  You are **NOT** attempting to force x64.exe to run as 32 bit.  You are trying to force Loader.exe, which *is* a 32 bit program to always choose to load the x86.exe 32 bit program while in a 64 bit environment... I especially don't understand why this answer was voted up, when it provided a link to the same question **YOU** pointed out that your question was explicitly **NOT** a duplicate of.

Comment: @ÆlessNorm Let me ask you one question, if you want to run 32 bit program always why dont you remove x64.exe and use x32.exe alone.

Comment: @gladiator2345 Think of it as if Loader.exe creates those files at run-time, theres no way for me to just double-click x32.exe and start it.
Either way, I found out how to force 32-bit after hours of wrapping my head around pointers, but I wont bother answering my own question as this topic is now closed for no reason.

Comment: @less Norm   You should have asked it in stackoverflow rather than in superuser as it is related to programming. That is why your question was misinterpreted by most of us. If you had asked in stack overflow it would have got good responses.